# Finding the number of patients who died because of caries

Tags: mysql

I'm asked to find the number of patients who died because of caries.

In particular I somewhat confused about how to use `COUNT()` together with the `SELECT` clause.

> **Admission-Diagnosis:**
>
> Adm_ID *//Admission Number (Admission to the hospital)*
>
> Diag_ID *//Diagnosis ID*
>
> **Admission:**
>
> Adm_ID *//Admission Number (Admission to the hospital)*
>
> Pat_ID *//Patient ID*
>
> Date_Adm *// Admission Date*
>
> Date_Discharge *//Discharge Date*
>
> Health_ID *// Health of patient at Discharge*

My attempt:

First, from the table Admission-Diagnosis I got those patients who went to the hospital because of caries

```
SELECT *
FROM Adm_Diag
WHERE Diag_ID = 900 /*900 code for caries
```

Then I find the Admission ID's for which the patients' health at discharge is 'Died'

```
SELECT * 
FROM Admission 
WHERE Health_ID = 23 /* 23: code for 'Die'
```

Then I merged these two table and found those Admission ID's where the patient died because of caries

```
SELECT e1.Adm_ID, Diag_ID, Health_ID
FROM (SELECT *FROM Adm_diag WHERE diag_ID = 900) e2, 
     (SELECT *FROM admission WHERE Health_id=23) e1
WHERE e2.Adm_ID=e1.Adm_ID
```

But I' having trouble with the 'counting' part. I don't really have idea how to use count and select clause simultaneously. I was trying to put all inside count ( `COUNT(SELECT e1.Adm_ID, Diag_ID, Health_ID...` ) but it doesn't work.

By the way, as I created the database, I put that one patient died because of this (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try :

```
select count(*) 
from Adm_diag ad
inner join admission a
on  ad.Adm_ID = a.Adm_ID
where ad.diag_ID = 900 and a.Health_id=23
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a count(*) with group by

```
SELECT e1.Adm_ID, e1.Diag_ID, e2.Health_ID, coun(*)
FROM  Adm_diag as a
INNER JOIN admission on e1.Adm_ID = e.Adm_ID
WHERE e1.Diag_ID = 900
AND e2.Health_ID = 23
group by e1.Adm_ID, e1.Diag_ID
```